# Deleting hash with nil value in the loop using Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

Given this Hash:

```
myXML = {:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('51ad8d83a3d24b3b9f000001'),
         "Comment"=>nil,
         "Line"=>
          [{"LineNumber"=>"3.1",
            "Item"=>"fruit-004",
            "Description"=>"Peach",
            "Quantity"=>"1",
            "UnitCost"=>"1610",
            "DeclaredValue"=>"0",
            "PointValue"=>"13"},
           {"LineNumber"=>"8.1",
            "Item"=>"fruit-001",
            "Description"=>"Fruit Set",
            "Quantity"=>"1",
            "UnitCost"=>"23550",
            "PointValue"=>"105",
            "PickLine"=>
             [{"PickLineNumber"=>"8.1..1",
               "PickItem"=>"fruit-002",
               "PickDescription"=>"Apple",
               "PickQuantity"=>"1"},
              {"PickLineNumber"=>"8.1..2",
               "PickItem"=>"fruit-003",
               "PickDescription"=>"Orange",
               "PickQuantity"=>"2"}]}],
         "MemberId"=>"A00000001",
         "MemberName"=>"Bruce",
         "DeliveryId"=>"6377935",
         "ShipToAddress1"=>"123-4567",
         "OrderDate"=>"05/08/13",
         "Payments"=>
          [{"PayType"=>"Credit Card", "Amount"=>"1000"},
           {"PayType"=>"Points", "Amount"=>"5390"}]}
```

I'm able to remove the key/value pair with "Comment" key that has `nil` value with the code:

```
myXML.each do |key, value|
  myXML.delete(key) if myXML[key] == nil
end
```

I believe there's a much better way to do this with less code in Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following code work as you expect?

```
myXML.delete_if{|key, value| value.nil?}
```

This is not appropriate of course if you intend to delete recursively.

Comment: Thanks, this did work for me, but I didn't understand when it's not appropriate.

Comment: Thanks to @Boris Stitnicky for editing my code. So, does it mean myXML.delete_if{|key, value| value.nil?} is faster than myXML.delete(key) if myXML[key] == nil ?

Comment: @oscar: I don't see how that worked with the data you show, as it is `myXML['ShipmentRequest']['Message']['Comment']` that needs deleting.

Comment: @Borodin Sorry, I just updated my post. Please see Edit above